# Map with sub regions in Python (Choropleth)

Tags: python, geopandas, choropleth

I am trying to plot a Choropleth map with subregions in Python for Armenia. Below you can see my data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_arm = {
         'subregion': ['Aragatsotn','Ararat','Armavir','Gegharkunik','Kotayk','Lori','Shirak','Syunik','Tavush','Vayots Dzor','Yerevan'],
         'Value':[0.2560,0.083,0.0120,0.9560,0.423,0.420,0.2560,0.043,0.0820,0.4560,0.019]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data_arm, columns = ['subregion',
                                   'Value'                                   
                                   ])
df
```

Namely, I want to plot a map for Armenia with all subregions. Unfortunately, I don't know how to implement it in this environment. Below you will see the code where I tried to do something

```
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

asia = world.query('continent == "Asia"')

EAC = ["ARM"]

asia["EAC"] = np.where(np.isin(asia["iso_a3"], EAC), 1, 0)

asia.plot(column="iso_a3")
plt.show()
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem and make Choropleth map similar as Choropleth map shown below:
[image]

Comment: How does your map currently look instead?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Totaly diffrent. Instead of one country and sub-regions, I see a whole continent with many countries

Comment: Maybe it's because you wrote `asia.plot(...)`? Should you not rather write something like `armenia.plot(...)`?

Comment: What is the africa variable?

Comment: @YaserJafariJ Asia is the name. Africa is wrong. I corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get geometry of sub-regions.  I used https://data.humdata.org/dataset/geoboundaries-admin-boundaries-for-armenia?

Then just need to join / merge to your data frame.

```
import pandas as pd

import geopandas as gpd

data_arm = {
    "subregion": [
        "Aragatsotn",
        "Ararat",
        "Armavir",
        "Gegharkunik",
        "Kotayk",
        "Lori",
        "Shirak",
        "Syunik",
        "Tavush",
        "Vayots Dzor",
        "Yerevan",
    ],
    "Value": [
        0.2560,
        0.083,
        0.0120,
        0.9560,
        0.423,
        0.420,
        0.2560,
        0.043,
        0.0820,
        0.4560,
        0.019,
    ],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data_arm, columns=["subregion", "Value"])

gdf = gpd.read_file(
    "https://github.com/wmgeolab/geoBoundaries/raw/3c96fa7257a71fbc6cb85284d36d2894e1882ff6/releaseData/gbOpen/ARM/ADM1/geoBoundaries-ARM-ADM1_simplified.geojson"
)

gdf.merge(df, left_on="shapeName", right_on="subregion").explore("Value")
```

[image]